# Keyboard Accessible Navigation Menu

Tags: accessibility

When navigating a website menu with a keyboard using tab, how do I prevent the tab sequence from selecting the submenu items? I would like the tab focus order to only access the top level links. If a user wants to access the submenu links, then they should be able to press the down arrow key to access them.

Comment: This is actually not the correct keyboard interaction per the [W3 navigation menubar accessible authoring guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menubar/menubar-navigation.html).  That page includes a description of the correct keyboard interactions and an example implementation you can use to base your own code upon.

Comment: Hello melissa. Any update on this? Did the answer help you progress on your navigation menu?

Answer (score 0):

Please beware Alexander’s comment that the [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) is discouraging the menubar pattern for navigation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menubar/menubar-navigation.html)

> CAUTION! Before considering use of the ARIA menubar pattern for site navigation, it is important to understand:
>
> - The menubar pattern requires complex functionality that is unnecessary for typical site navigation that is styled to look like a menubar with expandable sections or "fly outs".
> - A pattern more suited for typical site navigation with expandable groups of links is the disclosure pattern. For an example, see Example Disclosure Navigation Menu.

You can take a look at the [Disclosure Navigation Menu](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html) for guidelines and examples of what you are looking for.

Otherwise, if you really have the need of focus navigation inside a component by means other than <kbd>tab</kbd>, you will need some JavaScript to establish a Roving tab index.

That means you programmatically set `tabindex=0` to only one element, which should have focus—i.e. your sub menu item—and `tabindex=-1` to all others (inside the composite component).

```html
<ul class="menubar">
  <li><a href="…" tabindex="-1">Main menu item X</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="…" tabindex="0">Sub menu item 1</a></li>
      <!-- currently focused -->
      <li><a href="…" tabindex="-1">Sub menu item 2</a></li>
      …
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See [Keyboard Navigation Inside Components](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-keyboard-navigation-inside-components) for the JavaScript necessary.

Please beware as well that you will need some ARIA properties and states to indicate that a menu item *can* be opened, like `aria-haspopup="menu"`and `aria-expanded`, along with the proper roles.

See the [AGP Menu pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu/)